# Kendo UI Grid: show/export datetime column correctly for Json data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI grid. There is one column for 'Time Stamp', the type is DateTime. The data comes from a Json call (asp.net MVC project if matters). Because of this, I have to use a template to show the data in correct format.

```
{
    field: "TimeStamp", title: "Time Stamp", width: "80px"
    , headerAttributes: {
        style: "white-space: normal"
    }
    , template: '#= showDateTime(data.TimeStamp) #'
},
```

This way, it shows the datetime correctly in grid. However, when I export it, it export the Json data, i.e.

```
 /Date(1420524000000)/
```

Now, I have to convert this datetime data in Json call to string (with good format, so the sort feature in grid will work). I'm thinking that it has to have a better/simple way to show/export the data in correct way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify through the dataSource.schema.model.fields that your field is of type **date**. [This way](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model) you won't need to parse the data manually, you will have a good template by default, and you will see appropriate filter menu pickers.

Comment: thanks, that's what I did. It shows the data on screen ok, but when export, it exports as /Date(1420524000000)/ (the data is from Json call). That's my question.